# How can I get ALL Tweets from a given user AND a given hashtag?

Tags: php, javascript, twitter

I need to get/output all tweets from a particular user that contain a certain hashtag.  The Search API works, but only lets me get the most recent such tweets, and I need all of them.  Can this be done using PHP or JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that you are going to need to realize is will the server of twitter allow you to pull out everything?

Here is some information.
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Twitter returns tweets from around last 7 days . Other services like topsy.com and analytics.topsy.com may be helpful.